# _chsize raises assertation error on visual studio 2017

Tags: c, file, file-io, visual-studio-2017

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...
int function () {
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("list.txt", "rb+");
    ...
    int value;
    if (_chsize_s(f, value) == 0) return 1;
}
```

For some reason, the above snippet of code, when run in MS Visual Studio, generates an error at the _chsize_s() function. The following message pops up:

```
Debug Assertation Failed!
Expression: (fh >= 0 && (unsigned)fh < (unsigned)_nhandle)
```

I have no idea what to make of this, much less how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should be getting other warnings when you compile, possibly about implicit declarations. These warnings must be fixed, they are telling you where the true error is.

Comment: You should have gotten a compiler warning about this. The argument to `_chsize_s()` should be `int`, not `FILE*`.

Comment: See the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whx354w1.aspx

Comment: @Barmar I'm confused... if the argument type to pass is int, how can I mention which file I want to truncate? Sorry if that sounds extremely dumb. A working example or sample would be great if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the compiler's warnings or have them disabled. In order to fix the implicit declaration warning, you must include the header for `_chsize_s`:

```
#include <io.h>
```

This will fix the implicit declaration warning, and uncover the error, that `_chsize_s` is being called with the wrong type. The correct way to call it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <io.h>
...
int function(void) {
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("list.txt", "rb+");
    ...
    int value;
    if (_chsize_s(_fileno(f), value) == 0) return 1;
}
```

This shows how important it is not to ignore compiler warnings (with exceptions... most sane people will define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` when writing C with MSVC).